# Can not send request when screen is locked

Tags: android, react-native

My React Native (Android) application sends requests to the server when some events are triggered. But when I lock phone screen and in a few minutes event is triggered, app try to send request, but it fails. I tried `fetch` (error `Network request failed`) and `XMLHttpRequest`.

On some devices it works fine and I can't understand it depends on Android version or on device model.

Why does it happen and why on some (not all) devices? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with axios?

Comment: @GauravRoy axios uses XMLHttpRequest which does not work in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello issue not because of react-native development but as per android guideline,
Whenever device in `Doze` mode you can not access network or network resource directly for that you need to start some foreground service in your application or we can say foreground service, Actually, I don't know much about how to create and start foreground service in react-native, But maybe this word help you, Here also official document regarding `doze` mode

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: Thank you! It is my case  I also noticed that requests are sent when device is charging, but forgot to mention it in question! I will dive into it. Also we can manage battery restrictions in device battery settings, which solves problem, but it just workaround.

Comment: Your welcome, We are always here to help the community